# Pygame screen doesn't seem to refresh

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to make a Chrome Dino Game, however, I'm struggling with this problem:
On every frame, it should draw a new one at the new position and delete the previous one to make it look as if it's moving. HOWEVER, it remains at its previous position and a new image appears on its next position. I did write the pygame.display.update() code at the end of my maintop.
In the last time I ran into a similar problem, I managed to make it work by drawing a background image, but this time, it doesn't work.

following are my codes:

```
import pygame
import os
from random import randint
import schedule

pygame.init()

assets = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Assets")

screen_size = (screen_width, screen_height) = (1280, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 120

bg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(assets, "IMG_15.png"))

ground = 700

running = True

spacebaridx = 0
gamestart = False
tick_on_start = 0

obs1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(assets, "colourmat/light_green.png"))
pygame.transform.scale(obs1, (100, 200))

obs2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(assets, "colourmat/light_green.png"))
pygame.transform.scale(obs2, (120, 200))

obs3 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(assets, "colourmat/light_green.png"))
pygame.transform.scale(obs3, (150, 200))

ls_obs = []

def create_obs():
    k = randint(1, 3)
    if k == 1:
        info = {"type":1, "img":obs1, "x":screen_width, "y":ground - 200, "tox":2}
        ls_obs.append(info)
    if k == 2:
        info = {"type":2, "img":obs2, "x":screen_width, "y":ground - 200, "tox":2}
        ls_obs.append(info)
    else:
        info = {"type":3, "img":obs3, "x":screen_width, "y":ground - 200, "tox":2}
        ls_obs.append(info)

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(create_obs)

while running:
    dt = clock.tick(fps)

    if gamestart == True:
        game_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks() - tick_on_start
        schedule.run_pending()
    else:
        game_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if spacebaridx == 0: # Press space to start / to tell whether it's the first press
                    spacebaridx += 1
                    gamestart = True
                    tick_on_start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                else:
                    pass # Jump

    for o in ls_obs:
        o["x"] += o["tox"] * -1

    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    for o in ls_obs:
        screen.blit(o["img"], (o["x"], o["y"]))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because you aren't clearing the display within each frame. In `pygame`, in order to clear the display, we need to use the `fill` method. So in your code, at the top of your game loop before the event loop, add `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))`. This will fill your screen in the color black. Don't worry, the black won't be shown if you draw the background on top of it. Now, when you add a new image, the previous images won’t be displayed.

## Modified Game Loop

```
while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    dt = clock.tick(fps)

    if gamestart == True:
        game_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks() - tick_on_start
        schedule.run_pending()
    else:
        game_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if spacebaridx == 0: # Press space to start / to tell whether it's the first press
                    spacebaridx += 1
                    gamestart = True
                    tick_on_start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                else:
                    pass # Jump

    for o in ls_obs:
        o["x"] += o["tox"] * -1

    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    for o in ls_obs:
        screen.blit(o["img"], (o["x"], o["y"]))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```